# correct way to use kubernetes watches

Tags: kubernetes, watch

I am new to Kubernetes and I am not really sure on how to proceed to implement correctly a watch; especially I am not sure on how to deal with the resourceVersion parameter.

The goal is to watch for new pods with a specific label, and in case of error or disconnection from the cluster being able to restart the watch from the last event occurred.

I am doing something like this:

```cpp
// after setting up the connection and some parameters
String lastResourceVersion = null; // at beginning version is unknown
while (true) {
  try {
    Watch<V1Pod> watcher = Watch.createWatch(
            client,
            api.listNamespacedPodCall(namespace, pretty, fieldSelector, labelSelector, lastResourceVersion, forEver, true, null, null),
            new TypeToken<Watch.Response<V1Pod>>() {}.getType()
    );
    for (Watch.Response<V1Pod> item : watcher) {
      //increment the version
      lastResourceVersion = item.object.getMetadata().getResourceVersion();
      // do some stuff with the pod
    }
  } catch (ApiException apiException) {
    log.error("restarting the watch from "+lastResourceVersion, apiException);
  }
}
```

Is it correct to use the resourceVersion of a Pod to reinitialize the watch call? Is this number a kind of timestamp for all the events in the cluster, or different api will use different sequences?

Do I need to watch for specific exceptions? eg. in case of the resourceVersion is to old?

thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with cpp or java implementation of the watch functionality, but in general, you need to get/list resource and use its resourceVersion to setup a watch. Resource version itself is a numberthat corresponds to version of resource in etcd and is used to determine if there were any changes to the resource. Regarding your second point, yes you should catch exception if the resource version is too old. You can read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes

Comment: And here is an example of implementing list and watch and handle all possible exceptions in go (if you know cpp, it should be easy for you to undestand it) https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/reflector.go#L165

Answer (score 15):

Adam is right.

This is best explained by **https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes**

Quoting relevant parts (emphasis mine):

> When retrieving a **collection of resources** (either namespace or cluster scoped), the response from the server will contain a resourceVersion value that can be used to initiate a watch against the server.

... snip ...

> When the requested watch operations fail because the historical version of that resource is not available, clients must handle the case by recognizing the status code 410 Gone, clearing their local cache, **performing a list operation, and starting the watch from the resourceVersion returned by that new list operation.**

So before you call watch, you should list and pull the resourceVersion from the list (not the objects inside of it). Then start the watch with that resourceVersion. If the watch fails for some reason, you will have to list again and then use the resourceVersion from that list to re-establish the watch.

Comment: What if the watch failed and I need to restart the whole process, so I go to step 0 and get the list of the resources to pull the resource version out of it and use it to restart the watch.  Does it mean that the events that happened _while_ I was getting the update resource version are now gone for me?

Comment: @AntonDaneyko Yes. It can mean that. I believe the amount of event history that is kept and can be replayed depends on the backend storage. I think etcd3 keeps up to 5 minutes of history by default.

Comment: I have been looking around the web to see how is it dealt with in some existing Python-based projects and did not find much.  One hack that I stumbled upon is described here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-kubernetes-watch#1-resource-versions.  They extract the resource version from the error that K8s gives, when the input resource version is too old.  From a very brief look at the source code that produces this error: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/cacher/watch_cache.go#L620 it seems that the resource version returned so is legit.

Comment: [continue] But this hack is not mentioned anywhere in the K8s docs.  I have tried it out and it's been a few weeks since it's in prod and works stable.  Another direction I did not explore are bookmark objects described in the doc.  In my case I call `Watch.stream` with a timeout of 10 seconds to be able to gracefully stop the thread that does the watching (otherwise `Watch.stream` blocks and it's not possible to stop the thread if no events are coming in).  What is not clear to me is at which point bookmarks are generated, e.g. if a `Watch.stream` exits after a timeout then...

Comment: [continue]  it seems there's no way for the K8s to tell that and post a bookmark at this point.